# pythorch lightning fit_loop - TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable - in debug mode

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I'm training with pytorch-lightning and I get
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable inside fit_loop
I get this error only in debug mode and only when loading checkpoint.

If I run (and not debug) the code it runs properly.

Comment: You'll need a reproducible example, and it might end up being a bug you'd need to file an issue.

Comment: Create a minimal example that reproduces the issue and test it in both debug and non-debug modes. This can help isolate the problem and identify whether it is related to the specific codebase or the debugging environment.